# How to declare variables in a class that do not release?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I need to create two instances of two classes inside a view controller that stay alive for the entire time that view is open.

Inside theese one of theese classes I need to create a NSString and a NSDate that stays alive for the entire time the class is alive.

How do I do this?

Comment: Technically, you are asking the wrong question, since your code can always release or even overrelease any object even if you and/or some other code has retained it.  What you probably want to ask about is how to retain your instantiated or various returned objects so that they don't get autoreleased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define 2 variables in the class:

```
NSString* s;
NSDate* date;
```

Too keep the variables alive while the view is visible:

in viewDidAppear:

```
s = [@"A string" retain];
d = [[NSDate date] retain];
```

in viewDidDissapear:

```
[s release];
[d release];
```

if you need it for the entire time the class is alive move the code to the init and dealloc methods.

Comment: for some reason this throws an NSException when I do this in my own class.